# Way to send scheduled report emails from SSRS via AWS SES?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, reporting-services, amazon-ses

I have an instance of Microsoft SQL Server and have installed the Reporting Service (SSRS) on it. Is it possible to have the emails sent via Amazon's SES? I have it set up on other apps and would prefer to use it, but I'm having trouble finding where I could put in the different keys needed. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: @KeithFranklin Sorry, didn't see the message.No, There seems to be no way to do it. We had to set up an SMTP relay on the same server. We had the SSRS hit the SMTP relay, and the SMTP Relay went to AWS.

Comment: This is a frustrating problem that I also cannot figure out. If SES works in SQL Database Mail, why doesn't it work for Reporting Services?

Answer (score 0):

[AWS released Email Subscription support](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/08/amazon-rds-sql-server-email-subscription-sql-server-reporting-services/) for SRSS on Aug 26, 2022. This post from Sept 2022 [AWS RDS SSRS Email Subscription Set Up](https://lovethesql.com/aws-rds-ssrs-email-subscription-set-up/) explains how to use the feature with SES